# Why is API GW + ECS latency highest when traffic is low?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I have seen graphs similar to this for multiple services I manage, ECS and lambda backends alike. This example is an API GW + ECS backend.

The latency starts low at the beginning of the day (low traffic, rising), hits a stable average latency during peak times (high traffic, stable), and then the latency spikes at the end of the day as traffic falls (high traffic, falling).

This particular service has no scaling happening throughout the day, and CPU and memory utilization look healthy always.

[Latency vs SampleCount graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVlcY.png)

I've looked through all the service metrics and everything looks healthy. Is this expected behavior? What am I missing?